# How to debug when hypothesis produces flaky test error?

Tags: pytest, python-hypothesis

I am using the hypothesis python package for stateful testing.
I am getting the following error when I run my tests:

```
hypothesis.errors.Flaky: Unreliable assumption: An example which satisfied assumptions on the first run now fails it.
```

I understand what flaky error means from a similar post. I have a test which failed the first time but passed during the second time. I can understand from the log, which test has led to this failure. Hypothesis tries the same test sequence 4 times during the overall test run among which, 2 of them pass and 2 of them fail.

I have tried the failing test individually without hypothesis and it does not fail. I am trying to understand what leads to the flaky error. Is it possibly a bug in Hypothesis as given in the post below:

[What does Flaky: Hypothesis test produces unreliable results mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769887/what-does-flaky-hypothesis-test-produces-unreliable-results-mean)

How do I get around this? Please find the log file of the test run at the link:
https://github.com/aparnasbose/hypothesis/blob/master/flaky%20test

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly that your test is not deterministic for all inputs; there are some arguments or sequences of actions that Hypothesis can find which sometimes pass and sometimes fail.  Hypothesis considers this a bug in your test, and raises the `Flaky` error.

To diagnose this in more detail I'd need to see your actual source code.

FYI `verbose` verbosity is much more useful here than `debug` (which dumps too much internal state).  You may also want upgrade to Hypothesis >= 4.41.1 for improved statistics.